# Change value to 0 for rows in future dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Story:**
Basically I'm trying to showcase the month to date compared to the parallel month along with the delta.

Usually this will only be used for the current month. I was able to add future dates but the values for month to date is repeated for all the days in the future

**Objective:**
I would like the value to be 0 instead of the last value being repeated for the entire future dates

Essentially I would like the following code for my measure but its not working:

```
_Join MTD = 
IF(
    TODAY()<Current Row date,
    0,
    TOTALMTD(SUM('Fact Table'[Join Count]),'Date Table'[Date])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measures have no concept of a "current row". Measures are only affected by filter context. This can be confusing at first, because a table visual or a matrix visual has row labels, but these things are contributing filter context. The only place you will find row context is when adding a calculated column to a data table or within an iterator function.

You can probably do something like what I show below, but if you need any more help you'll need to share a sample of your data model (tables, columns, a few sample rows from each, relationships among tables) as well as the visual you're building.

```
_Join MTD = 
IF(
    TODAY () < MIN ( 'Date Table'[Date] ), // here we find the smallest day in filter
                                           // context with MIN. If there is only one day
                                           // in context, well then that is the min
    0,
    TOTALMTD ( SUM ( 'Fact Table'[Join Count] ), 'Date Table'[Date] )
)
```

It's a common idiom in DAX to take the `MAX` or `MIN` of a column when you want a "currently selected" value, though there are also more selective functions, such as `SELECTEDVALUE` if you want to guarantee that exactly one value is in filter context.

**Edit:** Per comments, the goal is to compare to yesterday, not today. We can simply take the measure above and modify its predicate as below:

```
( TODAY () - 1 ) < MIN ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
```

Arithmetic operators do reasonable things with date and time types in DAX. Also sometimes useful is that the `DATE` function deals gracefully with overflow and underflow, per the examples below:

```
DATE ( 2018, 1, 366 )  // => 2019-01-01
DATE ( 2018, 0, 1 )    // => 2017-12-01
DATE ( 2019, 2, 31 )   // => 2019-03-03
DATE ( 2019, 3, 0 )    // => 2019-02-28
```

So, if you must, you can abuse this function for date shifting as well, though it's usually a last resort.

Comment: thats absolutely awesome... i made a mistake in my question. I would like to make TODAY() - 1. since i dont get data for today. i tried dateadd(today(),-1,day) but it doesnt work. any ideas?

Comment: `TODAY () - 1` works. Arithmetic is defined for date and time types in DAX. The built in time-intelligence functions take a date column reference and return another set of dates as a 1-column table, for the most part (there are exceptions). Most of them need to operate on a well-formed date dimension of contiguous, non-repeating date values. This is weird compared to almost any other language, but it works very well in DAX, because basically everything you want to do involves manipulating filter context, which translates into exactly operations on tables/columns that return tables/columns.

Comment: very thorough explanation! very much appreciated !